# Web3j Contract Call Transaction - Always out of gas

Tags: gas

Playing around with Web3j, I set up a private, single-node blockchain with Geth using a genesis gas limit of 21 million.

I started a node with the following command:

```
geth --datadir ./geth/data --rpc --networkid 611234220438 --nodiscover --mine --minerthreads 1 --etherbase 0xda42738b67c0dca7a44e3601312b7e44a007e4d2 --targetgaslimit 21000000 --verbosity 3
```

When I deploy a contract (gas limit 1 million), everything works as expected. A little bit of ETH is taken out of my wallet and I can interact with the deployed contract. However, constant functions work. All non-constant transactions fail and consume all gas.

I am executing this contract function (Solidity 0.4.13):

`function skip() {}`

Here is the contract creation and transaction as confirmed by Geth logging:

Submitted contract creation

```
fullhash=0xb407cf8dcb79cca01bd7bf11fb2ed025f5316d978aef92f2373be290a389df50 contract=0x075abea5aae9997bbf83a4a7f03d57c5bad65303
```

Submitted transaction

```
fullhash=0xae6697b0ebf6754f2570433a57dea159c662d79f59ef9d820cda5ffeb83028a5 recipient=0xc7c1335a273a6ee519f5563357b93b3e365a74da
```

Here is the transaction receipt:

```
{
  "transactionHash":"0x43c42aee0e44df748b0b482240e79f1536df15196843a4f752083bda02a14b01",
  "transactionIndex":0,
  "blockHash":"0x86b599ac97879417c5ed3f96e8985e85e861774c010b340e50081fcb6b2248bf",
  "blockNumber":461,
  "cumulativeGasUsed":1000000,
  "gasUsed":1000000,
  "contractAddress":null,
  "root":"0x70b774d4d679210d1e88f0d8fc0d6f2e0aec457fe333d65515e6bf61de7e0ec6",
  "from":"0xd2b4519298938983586e09028a2ea302c667cf76",
  "to":"0x075abea5aae9997bbf83a4a7f03d57c5bad65303",
  "logs":[],
  "logsBloom":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "gasUsedRaw":"0xf4240",
  "transactionIndexRaw":"0x0",
  "blockNumberRaw":"0x1cd",
  "cumulativeGasUsedRaw":"0xf4240"
}
```

What might be going wrong? To me, it looks like the transaction might be failing, though I don't know why or how to tell.

Comment: If you can't call non-constant functions, even empty ones, it seems more an error when creating the transaction. Now solc 0.4.4 is pretty old I'd try with a newer version.

Comment: @Ismael good point, thanks. Updated to 0.4.13, yet the problem persists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Out of Gas invoking precompiled contracts on private blockchains](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1607/out-of-gas-invoking-precompiled-contracts-on-private-blockchains)

Comment: @Gawey I don't think it's a duplicate - that question concerns precompiled contracts built into the blockchain, whereas my contract is explicitly deployed. Until the contract is deployed, it does not have an address so I cannot assign it any Ether in the genesis file.

Comment: Ran that function on browser-solidity. It reports **Transaction cost: 21380 gas**, and **Execution cost: 108 gas**. You have probably verified this but, just to confirm, does the `from` account have enough ETH for the gas at the current gas price on your blockchain? At least, it did not throw, which would have consumed all gas sent.

Comment: Can you include the full transaction object that you are sending to your node (I'm assuming you are using JSON-RPC)?  It should include from, to, value, gas, gasprice, data.

Comment: @AjoyBhatia The from account has 1337 Ether specified in the genesis file, and confirmed when I request the balance from the blockchain.

Comment: @MicahZoltu I'm working on a minimal example, so I can post it on GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this was a misunderstanding of how Web3j works. I was expecting Web3j to deploy my latest contract on every run, but instead it was deploying my contract from a binary-encoded String.

In the `Contract` class generated by `web3j-maven-plugin`:

`static final String BINARY = "606060405234610000575b60008054600160a060020a03191633600160a060020a03161790555b5b6104b9806100366000396000f300606060405236156100675763ffffffff60e060020a6000350416630f656e2c811461006c578063189e(...)";`

This string *is* your compiled contract, not some kind of checksum for the `contract.sol` file. Unless you regenerate the `Contract` class on every change, it will keep using the old version, which did not have a function `skip` defined. I discovered this by starting from scratch.

Hopefully, the Geth devs will add a `contract function undefined` error some time - that would have led me down the right path a lot sooner!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this is same as in your case but I was also facing the same issue and the problem was that I was giving the wrong parameter for --datadir parameter.

I fixed that and the problem was solved.

Comment: Hi @anand011090, would you mind sharing the incorrect parameter, and how you changed it to make it work?

Comment: @Jodiug in --datadir parameter, i was specifying the wrong path but in actual, there wasn't any directory with that name. so it was starting the process as a new with no accounts and whenever I tried to run, it showed me out of gas. Well it was my carelessness. I don't know whether you also have same issue.

Comment: Can confirm this was not the problem - I tried using a faulty datadir (./geth/daata). This created a new folder and caused the error `Error processing transaction request: exceeds block gas limit` when deploying the contract. With the right data path, the contract is deployed correctly but the subsequent method calls fail.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned that all non-constant transactions are failing and constant functions are working. I am suspecting this could be due to lack of default account.

Try to set the default account address or associate an account address to the transaction like below:

```
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0]
```

or

```
contract.function(param,{from: eth.accounts[0]})
```

or

```
contract.function(param,{from: 'Your account address'})
```

Comment: Apparently, the `from` field is set in the transaction above. According to people, the issue might be that the account was locked. I used `Parity.build(HttpService()).personalUnlockAccount(wallet.address, walletPassword).sendAsync().get()` to unlock all my accounts, but unfortunately that had no effect.