# How can I verify a cryptographic signature that was produced by an Ethereum address key pair

Tags: solidity, cryptography, serpent

If I have a cryptographic signature from an Ethereum address key pair, how can I verify that signature?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Solidity and Serpent have `ecrecover` for this purpose.

> ecrecover(bytes32 data, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) returns
>   (address)

The function arguments are:

`data` is [what was signed](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/693/42).  Since it is 32 bytes, that usually means that the initial data is hashed first to 32 bytes, before it was signed.

`v`, `r`, `s` is the signature.  (`v` is the recovery id: a 1 byte value specifying the sign and finiteness of the curve point; this
value is in the range of [27, 30], however the [Ethereum protocol declares](https://github.com/ethereum/yellowpaper) the upper two possibilities, representing infinite values, invalid)

**Important** note with the examples below, [**sha3 is Keccak-256**](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/550/which-cryptographic-hash-function-does-ethereum-use).

Here is a [snippet in Solidity](https://github.com/obscuren/ethmail/blob/7a5686ae5c6bc30855b884d66bbf647ccc4b2174/ethmail.sol):

```
contract Auth {      
    function verify(address p, bytes32 hash, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) constant returns(bool) {
        // Note: this only verifies that signer is correct.
        // You'll also need to verify that the hash of the data
        // is also correct.
        return ecrecover(hash, v, r, s) == p;
    }
}
```

Here is an [example in Serpent](https://github.com/jorisbontje/sleth/blob/9ca3b53e0f3d969c89e6c330ccedd7c73894d721/test/test_ecrecover.py):

```
def test_ecrecover(h, v, r, s):
    return(ecrecover(h, v, r, s))
```

The corresponding test code in Python (requires `bitcoin` and `ethereum` packages):

```
import bitcoin as b
from ethereum import tester, utils


class TestECRecover(object):

    CONTRACT = """
def test_ecrecover(h, v, r, s):
    return(ecrecover(h, v, r, s))
"""

    def setup_class(cls):
        cls.s = tester.state()
        cls.c = cls.s.abi_contract(cls.CONTRACT)
        cls.snapshot = cls.s.snapshot()

    def setup_method(self, method):
        self.s.revert(self.snapshot)

    def test_ecrecover(self):
        priv = b.sha256('some big long brainwallet password')
        pub = b.privtopub(priv)

        msghash = b.sha256('the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog')
        V, R, S = b.ecdsa_raw_sign(msghash, priv)
        assert b.ecdsa_raw_verify(msghash, (V, R, S), pub)

        addr = utils.sha3(b.encode_pubkey(pub, 'bin')[1:])[12:]
        assert utils.privtoaddr(priv) == addr

        result = self.c.test_ecrecover(utils.big_endian_to_int(msghash.decode('hex')), V, R, S)
        assert result == utils.big_endian_to_int(addr)
```

---

Under the hood, `ecrecover` uses the `ECDSARECOVER` [precompiled contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/440/42) located at address 1.

---

Note: [Geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/commit/b59c8399fbe42390a3d41e945d03b1f21c1a9b8d) and [web3.eth.sign](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sign) will add a prefix to the `data` message before signing.

> The sign method calculates an Ethereum specific signature with:
>   sign(keccak256("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n" + len(message) +
>   message))).
>
> By adding a prefix to the message makes the calculated signature
>   recognisable as an Ethereum specific signature. This prevents misuse
>   where a malicious DApp can sign arbitrary data (e.g. transaction) and
>   use the signature to impersonate the victim.

For this case, the second argument to `verify()` must be `keccak256("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n", len(message), message)` instead of `keccak256(message)`.

Related: [ecrecover from Geth and web3.eth.sign](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15364/totally-baffled-by-ecrecover)

Comment: While already a very thorough answer, can you add what ecrecover returns in case of a good or invalid signature?

Comment: As I understand it, a good signature will return the address which did the signing. A bad signature will return a different address. There's no way to tell if a signature is valid or not without also knowing the address which was supposed to do the signing.

Comment: From the solidity docs on ecrecover: "recover the address associated with the public key from elliptic curve signature or return zero on error"

Comment: Thank you to the anonymous editor who added the important code comment: "You'll also need to verify that the hash of the data is also correct"

Comment: If the signature is wrong, you still get a valid address from this. So do you just have to make the signer include the address somewhere in the original message to check for correctness?

Comment: Or conversely @sudo  if hash is wrong,  you still get a valid but incorrect address.