# How do you sign an verify a message in javascript proving you own an Ethereum address?

Tags: signature, message

Is there a js library or even just pure js where I can sign and verify I own an Ethereum address?

Comment: What are you trying to sign, a transaction, file, etc..?

Comment: just sign a message offline. i need a js library i can include in my app. i just want one file and the associated code to do verify.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can sign a string of data using [`web3.eth.sign`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.9/web3-eth.html#sign)

The address you use needs to be unlocked and you can sign text like this:

```
> web3.eth.sign(<your address>, web3.sha3("Some text"))

0x32f689696d855dd79c73acd94b2374461261b6f3d00e758fa23d35607c0be3175cbc7a7ea02c7f23cd7ef9334b4718a3363dfe12c1c1de24da5f94eb68a67b6000"
```

The returned 130byte string is the concatenated r,s,v ECDSA values with the mapping:

```
r = signature[0:64]
s = signature[64:128]
v = signature[128:130]
```

While web3.js has no verification functions, Solidity has `ecrecover` call in the form:

```
ecrecover([sha3 hash of data], v, r, s)
```

[This question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2171/how-does-one-properly-use-ecrecover-to-verify-ethereum-signatures) explores usage of `ecrecover`.

Further, there is another [thread on the forum](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/2166/signature-generation-and-verification-in-solidity) in which the OP uses the Python Bitcoin module to verify signed data.

---

Update: Since v1.0 web3.js has verification functions. See the other answers here (eg. web3.eth.accounts.recover)

Comment: what is the js library i include with my app?

Comment: [web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/)

Comment: There's a bunch of files there. what is the ONE files I need to include in my app? thanks!

Comment: You can use `web3.js` from [github.com/ethereum/web3.js/tree/develop/dist](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/tree/develop/dist)

Comment: I would like to use this, but I get an error about my address: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/36561/signing-message-provided-address-is-invalid-the-capitalization-checksum-test-f

Comment: In versions < 1.0 you can call web3.sha3('test').
In 1.0 it was moved to web3.utils.sha3

Answer (score 14):

You can now verify signatures in web3 1.0 using [`web3.eth.accounts.recover`](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#recover)

```
const account = web3.eth.accounts[0];
const signature = await web3.eth.sign("Hello world", account);
const signingAddress = web3.eth.accounts.recover("Hello world", 
signature);
// account === signingAddress
```

Comment: What does the comment `// account === signingAddress` mean?

Comment: @JohnMurphy It's just a comment explaining that at the end, the variables account and signingAddress are equal addresses

Comment: what if the data to be recovered is dynamic or not known on the backend? why is that an necessary argument?

Comment: @Jim The backend _does_ need to know the message being signed. However, it doesn't need to be hardcoded, you can have your API receive the signature + the data that was signed.

Answer (score 6):

Notice that web3js will always prefix the string with "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n" before signing it. If you want to create a signature without this prefix, you could use [eth-crypto](https://github.com/pubkey/eth-crypto).

Comment: Note that currently web3 also concatenates message length when signing a message. So the final format is this: `\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n" + message.length + message`. See it here: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#id16

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

Proving or verifying that you own a public address is simply a matter of verifying that you have the private key for that address.

[eth-lightwallet](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet) will do that for you in JavaScript.

This is done completely "offline", as in the sense that you do not need to be connected to the Ethereum network, and [eth-lightwallet](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet) does not provide such a feature.

To communicate with the Etherum network one still needs a connection to a node. This can be done on a back-end server by using [Web3js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/) and [Geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/geth), or on the front-end by using [Web3js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/) and [MetaMask](https://metamask.io/).

Answer (score 1):

Solution for [ethers.js](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js) users:

```js
const hexPrivateKey = "0xae78c8b502571dba876742437f8bc78b689cf8518356c0921393d89caaf284ce";
const signingKey = new ethers.utils.SigningKey(hexPrivateKey);
const digest = ethers.utils.id("Some message");

const signature = signingKey.signDigest(digest);
const joinedSignature = ethers.utils.joinSignature(signature);
// 0xf0a760680a88ec3efff6e68ebce051b948cffd51d5814a448c0b32e35f2c753a6862077f01ae8edfccd524ba843b9340bcedfeafe62167fdd8517ca8528f398b1c

const recoveredAddress = ethers.utils.recoverAddress(digest, signature);
// 0x2f112ad225E011f067b2E456532918E6D679F978
```

Credits to [ricmoo](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/823#issuecomment-625953096) for the first part of the code snippet.

Answer (score -3):

I dont think so.

So far, we have [ethereum-lightwallet](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet) that relies on a RPC-open node to handle the block.

I think that there are some efforts to make a full-js client but, until now, you can't handle a wallet through pure JS.