# How to sign a message using Ethereum private key, locally without running a full node?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I need to sign locally, on a client (preferably in a browser) a message using my Ethereum private key. How can it be done without running full node locally? Message does not need to be sent to blockchain.

I have found this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13652/how-do-you-sign-an-verify-a-message-in-javascript-proving-you-own-an-ethereum-ad?newreg=bc39e02bca304017bbc18739638894d0), but I am looking for more details and best practices. For example, what function of web3.js is the best to use? 
I have also asked more specific question about web3.js functions [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25601/what-is-the-difference-between-web3-eth-sign-web3-eth-accounts-sign-web3-eth-p).

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum StackExchange! The accepted answer in the question you linked doesn't require geth, actually. You could use any client, like Metamask. I'm on the fence about whether that makes this question a duplicate.

Comment: I have updated the title and body of the question, to make it more specific and to solicit more details then provided [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13652/how-do-you-sign-an-verify-a-message-in-javascript-proving-you-own-an-ethereum-ad?newreg=bc39e02bca304017bbc18739638894d0).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sign a piece of data with the private key of an Ethereum address?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/693/how-can-i-sign-a-piece-of-data-with-the-private-key-of-an-ethereum-address)

Comment: @Ismael that answer is about signing data using full node, I am looking for signing locally without the use of full node.

Comment: The second answer has an example of signing using crypto-js, no geth required. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/696.

Comment: Thanks @Ismael. I see that crypto-js can be used indeed. But I would like to see maybe there will be an answer that will explain how to do siging locally using only web3.js