# Python ethereum create account using web3.py

Tags: web3.py

I am trying to create account for a user using web3.py in my local testrpc ethereum network. I have tried as per the [documentation](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.eth.account.html#web3.eth.account.Account.create). But I am getting the error

`AttributeError: 'Eth' object has no attribute 'account'`

Code I am trying :

`from web3 import Web3
w3 = Web3(YOUR_PROVIDER)
acct = w3.eth.account.create('KEYSMASH FJAFJKLDSKF7JKFDJ 1530')`

I could see there is `accounts` object in for `eth` object but that is not what I need.

What am I doing wrong ? I could see there is another type of account which is called PersonalAccount in the doc

What is the difference between these two ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update: web3.py v4 has been stable for a while, so the question and answer don't really make sense anymore. `w3.eth.account` is included in any modern install.*

---

In order to use the latest `w3.eth.account` feature, you will have to either:

- Wait for the v4 beta to come out (in the next week or so)
- Install web3.py from source

### Installing from source

```
git clone https://github.com/pipermerriam/web3.py.git
cd web3.py

virtualenv -p python3 venv
. venv/bin/activate

pip install -e .
python
>>> from web3 import Web3, ...
```

### Documentation Info

The [web3 documentation you're referring to](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is for "latest", which corresponds to the source code on master at http://github.com/pipermerriam/web3.py

To see what features are available in v3, see the [stable web3 documentation](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead.

Comment: Thanks. That is now clear. Could you please answer my another question ? The difference between account & personal account ?

Comment: Check out this answer for a full breakdown: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25601/what-is-the-difference-between-web3-eth-sign-web3-eth-accounts-sign-web3-eth-p/25610#25610

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple Ethereum libraries for Python, try using this one
https://github.com/pipermerriam/web3.py I didn't have good luck with the consensus one.

The docs list eth.account.create http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.eth.account.html

> git clone git@github.com:pipermerriam/web3.py.git
>
> cd web3.py
>
> virtualenv venv .
>
> venv/bin/activate
>
> pip install -r requirements-dev.txt
>
> pip install -e .
>
> python from web3 import Web3
>
> web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))
>
> web3.eth.account.create("asdf")

Comment: Thanks Matthew. We are using the pipermerriam only. The doc link I have specified above is of same.

Comment: I added a bigger sample. Its likely you have wrong web3 in your virtual env. See above if you do the sample above this works
web3.eth.account.create("asdf") however it doesn't work in my global python cause of a wrong dependency

Comment: No I have the correct web3 I think. I even tried with 

`pip install web3==3.16.1 `
on a seperate virtualenv.

I am getting the below error while running `pip install -e . python from web3 import Web3`

```Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python
```

Comment: Did you try the Singular Account?
web3.eth.account.create("asdf")

Comment: I could not complete the steps you mentioned. As in the above comment. Failed on the `pip install -e . python from web3 import Web3` step.

Comment: Those are two separate lines, stack overflow formats horribly see above now