# How to securely send a message

Tags: cpp-ethereum, encryption, smart-contract-wallets

I was wondering that can I encrypt a string, send it to a smart contract, for that to be decrypted only by some address's private key?

e.g `"Hello"` to be encrypted in a way that it would be decrypted only by the owner of `0x00000000000000000` who has its private key.

**EDIT**

Notice: I don't have the private key of `0x00000000000000000`

Comment: Please see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13652/how-do-you-sign-an-verify-a-message-in-javascript-proving-you-own-an-ethereum-ad

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt a message and store in your smart contract.

But to decrypt it, the only thing you can do is to make a call() to get encrypted data from the caller. It's a special function that will only read something on the smart contract.

You can't make a transaction with the private key as an argument but it will be FORBIDDEN because anyone would see the private key on the network and you will be hacked within secondes.

I don't see the point to store an encrypted message on the blockchain. But what you can do is using EIP712.

In our project [(CryptoPuzzle.com)](https://cryptopuzzle.com/en/details/piece/139) for token n°139 own by 0xDB59, I (address 0x28B9) made a bid to buy this token.
The bid is a signed message like this :

```
{
expiry: 1625503749
maker: "0x28b9dd12fa0dd64fdf3f7e02a02ab87c4167342c"
makerIds: Array []
makerWei: "10000000000000000"
taker: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
takerIds: Array [ 139 ]
takerWei: 0
sig: "0xfad5d54022f1a9d89ad0543b31dce38866e79e36cd40022ed626117ecf75d62e3e4f55d0c53f9b7a87c7acb9f8399743a9041f562e581e30a58da52dde9d8bf21b"
​​}
```

The important part is "sig" because it's EIP712 compatible so I can know that address 0x28b9 want to pay 10000000000000000 wei (0.01ETH) for token [ 139 ]. Please look at EIP712 to understand it.