# ecrecover() always returns 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Tags: solidity, remix, signature, verify, ecrecover

I'm aware of these posts

[How do you sign an verify a message in javascript proving you own an Ethereum address?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13652/how-do-you-sign-an-verify-a-message-in-javascript-proving-you-own-an-ethereum-ad?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[How does one properly use ecrecover to verify Ethereum signatures?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2171/how-does-one-properly-use-ecrecover-to-verify-ethereum-signatures)

---

I'd like to sign a message and then verify it. I use the following command line in the geth  terminal.

```
var msg = web3.sha3('Schoolbus')
var signature = web3.eth.sign(web3.eth.accounts[0], msg)
var r = signature.slice(0, 66)
var s = '0x' + signature.slice(66, 130)
var v = '0x' + signature.slice(130, 132)
v = web3.toDecimal(v)
```

Then I use the smart contract below, and call:

```
   call_ecover(r, s,  v, msg)
```

But what i get is: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

```
 pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
 contract Call_verify{

  function call_ecover(bytes32 r, bytes32 s, uint8 v, 
  bytes32 hash)external pure returns (address){
  bytes memory prefix = "\x19Ethereum Signed 
  Message:\n32";    
  bytes32 prefixedHash = 
  keccak256(abi.encodePacked(prefix,hash));  
  return ecrecover(prefixedHash, v, r, s);    
  } 
 
}
```

Note that I'm using compiler version 0.5.3 on remix.

**Question**: Why cannot I get the return value of ecrecover() function in my contract? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, it’s `web3.eth.sign(data, address)`. I think you inversed the parameters. See https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#sign.

Also, do you send the good `hash` in the `call_ecover` function? I think you need to send the hash of `msg` (in your case, a hash of a hash: `web3.sha3(msg)`).

Comment: You don't have to send hash of hash, you have to send what was signed.

Comment: In the code, `msg` is the hash of `'Schoolbus’` and `call_ecover` needs the hash of the `msg` so in this case it’s a hash of a hash.

Comment: In a digital signature, when you are signing a message, it means you are signing a hash of the message. This is used to verify the origin as well as integrity of the message. You can check the working logic in my answer. I have hashed `SchoolBus` only once before signing. This same hash is given as an input to the `ecrecover` function in solidity

Comment: Yes I agree with you and your code seems more clean but in the example of Ay. the message is a hash.

Answer (score 2):

The following code snippet works:

```java
    //pragma solidity ^0.5.0
    function checkSignature(bytes32 h, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) public pure returns (address signer) {
        bytes memory prefix = "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32";    
        bytes32 prefixedHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(prefix,h));  
        signer = ecrecover(prefixedHash, v, r, s); 
    }
```

```js
    //web3 1.0
    //multisig is my constract instance and second is an account address.

    const message = "SchoolBus";
    const h = web3.utils.soliditySha3(message);
    let signature = await web3.eth.sign(h, second);

    var r = signature.slice(0, 66);
    var s = "0x" + signature.slice(66, 130);
    var v = "0x" + signature.slice(130, 132);
    v = web3.utils.toDecimal(v);
    v = v + 27;

    const result = await multisig.checkSignature(h, v, r, s);
    //result === second
```

Note: `web3.sha3` is a method from v0.2x. in v1.0 the function used is as described above. `ecrecover` gets the signer details from a piece of data, usually a hash and the signature obtained when the signer signed the data.