# Ethereum ecrecover signature verification and encryption

Tags: solidity, signature, encryption, ecrecover

The question of signing and verifying signatures with Solidity has been asked in these questions, both of which I have tried to study:

[How can I sign a piece of data with the private key of an Ethereum address?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/693/how-can-i-sign-a-piece-of-data-with-the-private-key-of-an-ethereum-address)

[How can I verify a cryptographic signature that was produced by an Ethereum address key pair](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/710/how-can-i-verify-a-cryptographic-signature-that-was-produced-by-an-ethereum-addr/718#718)

However, there are still pieces of information that I appear to be missing.

First off, I would like to start with the question about signing. In the example, the string `Schoolbus` is signed by the address `0xd1ade25ccd3d550a7eb532ac759cac7be09c2719`, and the resulting signature is `0x2ac19db245478a06032e69cdbd2b54e648b78431d0a47bd1fbab18f79f820ba407466e37adbe9e84541cab97ab7d290f4a64a5825c876d22109f3bf813254e8601`.

So far, so good. Now, what I'd like to do is verify using `ecrecover` that the signature is indeed correct for the given address and datum. The thing is, `ecrecover` takes four arguments: `ecrecover(h, v, r, s)`. Aside from `h` being the hash, and `{v, r, s}` somehow comprising the signature, what exactly do v, r, and s stand for? And how do I obtain all the values necessary from the single string `0x2ac19db245478a06032e69cdbd2b54e648b78431d0a47bd1fbab18f79f820ba407466e37adbe9e84541cab97ab7d290f4a64a5825c876d22109f3bf813254e8601`?

What I know is that `ecrecover` returns an address, and verifying a signature is essentially a matter of comparing the resulting address with the expected one. Yet the whole procedure seems unnecessarily complicated.

Aside from this, I was also wondering how I could produce a signature, either like this `0x2ac19db245478a06032e69cdbd2b54e648b78431d0a47bd1fbab18f79f820ba407466e37adbe9e84541cab97ab7d290f4a64a5825c876d22109f3bf813254e8601` or a set of `{h, v, r, s}` using Solidity alone, without the RPC-JSON detour as is the case in the question – provided I know a private key?

Comment: Check out https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/workflow-on-signing-a-string-with-private-key-followed-by-signature-verificatio/1794#1794
Here I also list the procedure for extracting r, v, and s from the signature string. I agree that this procedure is a bit too complicated, and I expressed this issue here: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/79

Comment: I'm afraid that the question in question is not in Solidity. What I am trying to accomplish has to be executed within a contract.

Comment: Can you expand a bit on why you would want to sign something inside a contract? As has been mentioned this will expose the private key of the signer to everyone

Comment: I merely want to verify a signature in the format specified above within a contract. The signing part would be just for unit testing.

Comment: The verification procedure is done in a solidity contract in the question I linked to

Comment: The call to `ecrecover` is, yes. But I don't have an execution environment in JavaScript surrounding it that would be able to prepare the signature string into the separate components before feeding it into a Solidity contract. The contract itself has to be able to handle the raw signature string.

Comment: In principle, I'm possibly just looking for Solidity equivalents of `web3.toDecimal` and `String.prototype.slice`. I'm trying out all the answers in a contract as they come.

Comment: @arik  "verifying a signature is essentially a matter of comparing the resulting address with the expected one" is not what `ecrecover` does. It compares the hash passed in with the hash message decrypted from the signature to see that they match, then returns the address if true.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

v, r, and s are parameters that can be parsed from the signature.  Here's a good example from the ethereumjs utils library:

```
  var sig = secp256k1.sign(msgHash, privateKey)
  var ret = {}
  ret.r = sig.signature.slice(0, 32)
  ret.s = sig.signature.slice(32, 64)
  ret.v = sig.recovery + 27
```

Note how you can parse each value from a given signature.

Even though you may sign two different msgs with the same private key, the signing process (internally) generates a random nonce value (k) that is used as part of the calculation and must be different for each generated signature.

r and s along with the associated public key help to validate if the signature is legit.

Note: I'm no cryptographer. This is what I've dug up trying to answer the same questions you have. I'd suggest looking at some of the online resources for elliptic curves.

> Aside from this, I was also wondering how I could produce a signature, either like this 0x2ac19db245478a06032e69cdbd2b54e648b78431d0a47bd1fbab18f79f820ba407466e37adbe9e84541cab97ab7d290f4a64a5825c876d22109f3bf813254e8601 or a set of {h, v, r, s} using Solidity alone, without the RPC-JSON detour as is the case in the question – provided I know a private key?

The problem you'd have generating a signature from within Solidity is you'd have to expose the private key. Alternatively, you could generate a signature outside of the normal Ethereum transaction process using one of the many elliptic curve libraries and send that resulting signature to a contract.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Now, if I have just the signature string, how do I get the signature object from it? The signature string itself does not contain a `recovery` property, I'm afraid. Also, just making sure: Is the hash necessary for `ecrecover` sha256?

Comment: Is there any way v can be recalculated? I'm afraid `ecrecover` won't work without passing in the right value.

Comment: IIUC when a signature is DER encoded, it only stores the r and s points, and throws away "v". When I want to supply a "v" value I just try them both. So where pubkey_decompressed is the public key that created the ethereum address:

v_but_not_really, r, s = bitcoin.der_decode_sig(sig)

for possible_v in [27, 28]:
 possible_pub = bitcoin.encode_pubkey(bitcoin.ecdsa_raw_recover(msg_hash,  (possible_v, r, s)), 'hex')
 if pubkey_decompressed == possible_pub:
  return possible_v

Comment: In the string that is returned when using eth.sign, v is included. The last two hex characters represent v. More on this here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/workflow-on-signing-a-string-with-private-key-followed-by-signature-verificatio/1794#1794

Comment: to accomplish this signing process, what client or what environment do I need?
"  var sig = secp256k1.sign(msgHash, privateKey)
  var ret = {}
  ret.r = sig.signature.slice(0, 32)
  ret.s = sig.signature.slice(32, 64)
  ret.v = sig.recovery + 27"

Answer (score 7):

> What exactly do v, r, and s stand for?

- `r` is the `R.x` value of the signature's `R` point.
- `s` is the signature proof for `R.x`
- `v` is a recovery parameter used to ease the signature verification.

`v` is not required but often included. **But what is `v`?**

Since the signature only includes the `x` coordinate of the point `R`, there are either 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4 matching `y` coordinates over the Secp256k1 elliptic curve. These four potential candidates are encoded in something called `recovery_id`.

A recovery ID can have the values `0..3` depending on the following conditions:

- Is `R.y` even and `R.x` less than the curve order `n`: `recovery_id := 0`
- Is `R.y` *odd* and `R.x` less than the curve order `n`: `recovery_id := 1`
- Is `R.y` even and `R.x` *more* than the curve order `n`: `recovery_id := 2`
- Is `R.y` *odd* and `R.x` *more* than the curve order `n`: `recovery_id := 3`

Now we know how to get to the recovery ID. `v` is simply `v = recory_id + 27` for Bitcoin. In addition to `v` values of `27..30` that only reflect the recovery ID, there is also the notion of recovering compressed public keys, using the same recovery ID but a `v` of `v = recovery_id + 31`.

But we are not talking about Bitcoin, so last but not least, you want to look at [EIP-155](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md) because we no longer use the `+ 27` part that Bitcoin used to prevent replay protection:

```
v = chain_id * 2 + 35 + recovery_id
```

In Ethereum, `v` reflects the chain for replay protection and the ID for signature recovery.

> And how do I obtain all the values necessary from the single string `0x2ac19db245478a06032e69cdbd2b54e648b78431d0a47bd1fbab18f79f820ba407466e37adbe9e84541cab97ab7d290f4a64a5825c876d22109f3bf813254e8601`?

This is just a concatenated string of `"#{v}#{r}#{s}"` with:

- `v = 0x2a`
- `r = 0xc19db245478a06032e69cdbd2b54e648b78431d0a47bd1fbab18f79f820ba407`
- `s = 0x466e37adbe9e84541cab97ab7d290f4a64a5825c876d22109f3bf813254e8601`

The `v` is 42.

```ruby
chain_id = (v - 35) / 2
```

Now, we can verify that the `v` of 42 is only valid on the chain with ID 3 (Ropsten).

> What I know is that `ecrecover` returns an address, and verifying a signature is essentially a matter of comparing the resulting address with the expected one. Yet the whole procedure seems unnecessarily complicated.

I know this is not a question, but this is literally how elliptic-curve cryptography works: it's just mathematical operations with various points on a curve.

An address is just a pretty-formatted version of the public key; the public key is just a point on the Secp256k1 elliptic curve.

A signature is just another point. And if you do public key magic and signature magic, at the end of this math-heavy process you have two points (public keys) and if they are exact matches, the signature can be considered *verified*.

That `ecrecover` returns an `address` is just for your convenience: you can directly compare if the signature address matches the signer address - and that is much easier to do in Solidity as opposed to deal with uncompressed public keys.

I hope this sheds some light one this question.

Comment: Hi, in what case can there be more than 2 "y" coordinates for one x? as far as I understand, the curve is mirrored horizontally, which means there can be 0 (if the x point is to the left of the curve), 1 (if the x point is at the exact middle of the curve), and 2 everywhere else.

Comment: The curve is not really a "curve," it looks more like a field of sprinkled dots. So, there are x-values where you don't have any corresponding y-value. Approximately half of the possible choices for x correspond to usually two points. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/98364