# Is there a command line like RSA_verify in Ethereum

Tags: contract-design

I want to know if there is command line in Ethereum can do the RSA signature verification that we can directly use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short no. Ethereum uses Elliptic Curves for signatures

You can see all command line options by running: `geth help`.

Comment: then can the contract directly do Elliptic Curves signatures verification?

Comment: You can check elliptic curve signatures (I'm pretty sure it's secp256k1 curve only.. same curve as Bitcoin) with ecrecover. There is no RSA signature verification yet, but that seems to be in the works for some future release ( https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/74 ).

Comment: @wang See this post on signature verification: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2256/ethereum-ecrecover-signature-verification-and-encryption