# Errors in when compiling the BLS signature in remix?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, signature, pairings

Etherum can verify BLS signatures, In this answer [Does Ethereum support pairing operations?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/59293/does-ethereum-support-pairing-operations/59315#59315)

There is an example of how to verify BLS in solidity. However, when I tried to test the code in remix, 
 Update: Here is the whole contract

```
           pragma solidity ^0.4.14;

/*
   Example of how to verify BLS signatures and BGLS aggregate signatures in 
     Ethereum.

     Signatures are generated using https://github.com/Project-Arda/bgls
       Code is based on https://github.com/jstoxrocky/zksnarks_example
                */

   contract BLSExample {
      struct G1Point {
     uint X;
      uint Y;
     }
// Encoding of field elements is: X[0] * z + X[1]
struct G2Point {
    uint[2] X;
    uint[2] Y;
}

/// @return the generator of G1
function P1() internal returns (G1Point) {
    return G1Point(1, 2);
}

/// @return the generator of G2
function P2() internal returns (G2Point) {
    return G2Point(
        [11559732032986387107991004021392285783925812861821192530917403151452391805634,
        10857046999023057135944570762232829481370756359578518086990519993285655852781],

        [4082367875863433681332203403145435568316851327593401208105741076214120093531,
        8495653923123431417604973247489272438418190587263600148770280649306958101930]
    );
}

//Example of BLS signature verification
function verifyBLSTest() returns (bool) {

    bytes memory message = hex"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";

    G1Point memory signature = G1Point(11181692345848957662074290878138344227085597134981019040735323471731897153462, 6479746447046570360435714249272776082787932146211764251347798668447381926167);

    G2Point memory v = G2Point(
        [18523194229674161632574346342370534213928970227736813349975332190798837787897, 5725452645840548248571879966249653216818629536104756116202892528545334967238],
        [3816656720215352836236372430537606984911914992659540439626020770732736710924, 677280212051826798882467475639465784259337739185938192379192340908771705870]
    );

    G1Point memory h = hashToG1(message);

    return pairing2(negate(signature), P2(), h, v);
}

//Example of BGLS signature verification with 2 signers
//Note that the messages differ in their last character.
function verifyBGLS2() returns (bool) {

    uint numberOfSigners = 2;

    G1Point memory signature = G1Point(7985250684665362734034207174567341000146996823387166378141631317099216977152, 5471024627060516972461571110176333017668072838695251726406965080926450112048);

    bytes memory message0 = hex"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";
    bytes memory message1 = hex"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";

    G2Point memory v0 = G2Point(
        [15516709285352539082439213720585739724329002971882390582209636960597958801449, 19324541677661060388134143597417835654030498723817274130329567224531700170734],
        [16550775633156536193089672538964908973667410921848053632462693002610771214528, 10154483139478025296468271477739414260393126999813603835827647034319242387010]
    );

    G2Point memory v1 = G2Point(
        [14125383697019450293340447180826714775062600193406387386692146468060627933203, 10886345395648455940547500614900453787797209052692168129177801883734751834552],
        [13494666809312056575532152175382485778895768300692817869062640713829304801648, 10580958449683540742032499469496205826101096579572266360455646078388895706251]
    );

    G1Point memory h0 = hashToG1(message0);
    G1Point memory h1 = hashToG1(message1);

    G1Point[] memory a = new G1Point[](numberOfSigners + 1);
    G2Point[] memory b = new G2Point[](numberOfSigners + 1);
    a[0] = negate(signature);
    a[1] = h0;
    a[2] = h1;
    b[0] = P2();
    b[1] = v0;
    b[2] = v1;

    return pairing(a, b);
}

//Example of BGLS signature verification with 3 signers
//Note that the messages differ in their last character.
function verifyBGLS3() returns (bool) {

    uint numberOfSigners = 3;

    G1Point memory signature = G1Point(385846518441062319503502284295243290270560187383398932887791670182362540842, 19731933537428695151702009864745685458233056709189425720845387511061953267292);

    bytes memory message0 = hex"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";
    bytes memory message1 = hex"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";
    bytes memory message2 = hex"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";

    G2Point memory v0 = G2Point(
        [1787282038370667094324364195810339512415273589223814213215040505578200405366, 414568866548933554513940840943382696902163788831396286279770126458218272940],
        [6560020551439455112781785895092032589010633560844445112872109862153018855017, 19411093226570397520343120724285433000937737461010544490862811136406407315543]
    );

    G2Point memory v1 = G2Point(
        [14831125462625540363404323739936082597729714855858291605999144010730542058037, 8342129546329626371616639780890580451066604883761980695690870205390518348707],
        [808186590373043742842665711030588185456231663895663328011864547134240543671, 1856705676948889458735296604372981546875220644939188415241687241562401814459]
    );

    G2Point memory v2 = G2Point(
        [12507030828714819990408995725310388936101611986473926829733453468215798265704, 16402225253711577242710704509153100189802817297679524801952098990526969620006],
        [18717845356690477533392378472300056893077745517009561191866660997312973511514, 20124563173642533900823905467925868861151292863229012000403558815142682516349]
    );

    G1Point memory h0 = hashToG1(message0);
    G1Point memory h1 = hashToG1(message1);
    G1Point memory h2 = hashToG1(message2);

    G1Point[] memory a = new G1Point[](numberOfSigners + 1);
    G2Point[] memory b = new G2Point[](numberOfSigners + 1);
    a[0] = negate(signature);
    a[1] = h0;
    a[2] = h1;
    a[3] = h2;
    b[0] = P2();
    b[1] = v0;
    b[2] = v1;
    b[3] = v2;

    return pairing(a, b);
}

/// @return the result of computing the pairing check
/// e(p1[0], p2[0]) *  .... * e(p1[n], p2[n]) == 1
/// For example pairing([P1(), P1().negate()], [P2(), P2()]) should
/// return true.
function pairing(G1Point[] p1, G2Point[] p2) internal returns (bool) {
    require(p1.length == p2.length);
    uint elements = p1.length;
    uint inputSize = elements * 6;
    uint[] memory input = new uint[](inputSize);

    for (uint i = 0; i < elements; i++)
    {
        input[i * 6 + 0] = p1[i].X;
        input[i * 6 + 1] = p1[i].Y;
        input[i * 6 + 2] = p2[i].X[0];
        input[i * 6 + 3] = p2[i].X[1];
        input[i * 6 + 4] = p2[i].Y[0];
        input[i * 6 + 5] = p2[i].Y[1];
    }

    uint[1] memory out;
    bool success;

    assembly {
        success := call(sub(gas, 2000), 8, 0, add(input, 0x20), mul(inputSize, 0x20), out, 0x20)
    // Use "invalid" to make gas estimation work
        switch success case 0 {invalid}
    }
    require(success);
    return out[0] != 0;
}

/// Convenience method for a pairing check for two pairs.
function pairing2(G1Point a1, G2Point a2, G1Point b1, G2Point b2) internal returns (bool) {
    G1Point[] memory p1 = new G1Point[](2);
    G2Point[] memory p2 = new G2Point[](2);
    p1[0] = a1;
    p1[1] = b1;
    p2[0] = a2;
    p2[1] = b2;
    return pairing(p1, p2);
}

function hashToG1(bytes message) internal returns (G1Point) {
    uint256 h = uint256(keccak256(message));
    return mul(P1(), h);
}

function modPow(uint256 base, uint256 exponent, uint256 modulus) internal returns (uint256) {
    uint256[6] memory input = [32, 32, 32, base, exponent, modulus];
    uint256[1] memory result;
    assembly {
        if iszero(call(not(0), 0x05, 0, input, 0xc0, result, 0x20)) {
            revert(0, 0)
        }
    }
    return result[0];
}

/// @return the negation of p, i.e. p.add(p.negate()) should be zero.
function negate(G1Point p) internal returns (G1Point) {
    // The prime q in the base field F_q for G1
    uint q = 21888242871839275222246405745257275088696311157297823662689037894645226208583;
    if (p.X == 0 && p.Y == 0)
        return G1Point(0, 0);
    return G1Point(p.X, q - (p.Y % q));
}

/// @return the sum of two points of G1
function add(G1Point p1, G1Point p2) internal returns (G1Point r) {
    uint[4] memory input;
    input[0] = p1.X;
    input[1] = p1.Y;
    input[2] = p2.X;
    input[3] = p2.Y;
    bool success;
    assembly {
        success := call(sub(gas, 2000), 6, 0, input, 0xc0, r, 0x60)
    // Use "invalid" to make gas estimation work
        switch success case 0 {invalid}
    }
    require(success);
}
/// @return the product of a point on G1 and a scalar, i.e.
/// p == p.mul(1) and p.add(p) == p.mul(2) for all points p.
function mul(G1Point p, uint s) internal returns (G1Point r) {
    uint[3] memory input;
    input[0] = p.X;
    input[1] = p.Y;
    input[2] = s;
    bool success;
    assembly {
        success := call(sub(gas, 2000), 7, 0, input, 0x80, r, 0x60)
    // Use "invalid" to make gas estimation work
        switch success case 0 {invalid}
    }
    require(success);
}
```

}

I got the following 2 errors in remix:

```
browser/Pairing.sol:187:13: ParserError: Literal, identifier or instruction 
expected. if iszero(call(not(0), 0x05, 0, input, 0xc0, result, 0x20)) {
```

and

```
 browser/Pairing.sol:187:16: ParserError: Expected token LParen got 
 'Identifier'  if iszero(call(not(0), 0x05, 0, input, 0xc0, result, 0x20)) { 
  ^
```

Could you please help me figure out how to solve these errors ?

The original code contract is available on github https://gist.github.com/BjornvdLaan/ca6dd4e3993e1ef392f363ec27fe74c4

Comment: The code doesn't generate any errors to me. Can you paste your contract?

Comment: @alberto I update it. it is from this answer. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/59293/does-ethereum-support-pairing-operations?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the compiler version in Remix. If you set `0.4.24` or `0.4.25` (for example) the code works with some warnings. You need to make some modifications in the code if you want to use the compiler version `0.5.0` or later.

Modified code for `0.5.x` (with warnings):

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

/*
   Example of how to verify BLS signatures and BGLS aggregate signatures in 
     Ethereum.

     Signatures are generated using https://github.com/Project-Arda/bgls
       Code is based on https://github.com/jstoxrocky/zksnarks_example
                */

   contract BLSExample {
      struct G1Point {
     uint X;
      uint Y;
     }
// Encoding of field elements is: X[0] * z + X[1]
struct G2Point {
    uint[2] X;
    uint[2] Y;
}

/// @return the generator of G1
function P1() internal returns (G1Point memory) {
    return G1Point(1, 2);
}

/// @return the generator of G2
function P2() internal returns (G2Point memory) {
    return G2Point(
        [11559732032986387107991004021392285783925812861821192530917403151452391805634,
        10857046999023057135944570762232829481370756359578518086990519993285655852781],

        [4082367875863433681332203403145435568316851327593401208105741076214120093531,
        8495653923123431417604973247489272438418190587263600148770280649306958101930]
    );
}

//Example of BLS signature verification
function verifyBLSTest() public returns (bool) {

    bytes memory message = hex"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";

    G1Point memory signature = G1Point(11181692345848957662074290878138344227085597134981019040735323471731897153462, 6479746447046570360435714249272776082787932146211764251347798668447381926167);

    G2Point memory v = G2Point(
        [18523194229674161632574346342370534213928970227736813349975332190798837787897, 5725452645840548248571879966249653216818629536104756116202892528545334967238],
        [3816656720215352836236372430537606984911914992659540439626020770732736710924, 677280212051826798882467475639465784259337739185938192379192340908771705870]
    );

    G1Point memory h = hashToG1(message);

    return pairing2(negate(signature), P2(), h, v);
}

//Example of BGLS signature verification with 2 signers
//Note that the messages differ in their last character.
function verifyBGLS2() public returns (bool) {

    uint numberOfSigners = 2;

    G1Point memory signature = G1Point(7985250684665362734034207174567341000146996823387166378141631317099216977152, 5471024627060516972461571110176333017668072838695251726406965080926450112048);

    bytes memory message0 = hex"7b0a2020226f70656e223a207b0a20202020227072696365223a2039353931372c0a202020202274696d65223a207b0a20202020202022756e6978223a20313438333134323430302c0a2020202020202269736f223a2022323031362d31322d33315430303a30303a30302e3030305a220a202020207d0a20207d2c0a202022636c6f7365223a207b0a20202020227072696365223a2039363736302c0a202020202274696d65223a207b0a20202020202022756e6978223a20313438333232383830302c0a2020202020202269736f223a2022323031372d30312d30315430303a30303a30302e3030305a220a202020207d0a20207d2c0a2020226c6f6f6b7570223a207b0a20202020227072696365223a2039363736302c0a20202020226b223a20312c0a202020202274696d65223a207b0a20202020202022756e6978223a20313438333232383830302c0a2020202020202269736f223a2022323031372d30312d30315430303a30303a30302e3030305a220a202020207d0a20207d0a7d0a6578616d706c652e636f6d2f6170692f30";
    bytes memory message1 = hex"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";

    G2Point memory v0 = G2Point(
        [15516709285352539082439213720585739724329002971882390582209636960597958801449, 19324541677661060388134143597417835654030498723817274130329567224531700170734],
        [16550775633156536193089672538964908973667410921848053632462693002610771214528, 10154483139478025296468271477739414260393126999813603835827647034319242387010]
    );

    G2Point memory v1 = G2Point(
        [14125383697019450293340447180826714775062600193406387386692146468060627933203, 10886345395648455940547500614900453787797209052692168129177801883734751834552],
        [13494666809312056575532152175382485778895768300692817869062640713829304801648, 10580958449683540742032499469496205826101096579572266360455646078388895706251]
    );

    G1Point memory h0 = hashToG1(message0);
    G1Point memory h1 = hashToG1(message1);

    G1Point[] memory a = new G1Point[](numberOfSigners + 1);
    G2Point[] memory b = new G2Point[](numberOfSigners + 1);
    a[0] = negate(signature);
    a[1] = h0;
    a[2] = h1;
    b[0] = P2();
    b[1] = v0;
    b[2] = v1;

    return pairing(a, b);
}

//Example of BGLS signature verification with 3 signers
//Note that the messages differ in their last character.
function verifyBGLS3() public returns (bool) {

    uint numberOfSigners = 3;

    G1Point memory signature = G1Point(385846518441062319503502284295243290270560187383398932887791670182362540842, 19731933537428695151702009864745685458233056709189425720845387511061953267292);

    bytes memory message0 = hex"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";
    bytes memory message1 = hex"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";
    bytes memory message2 = hex"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";

    G2Point memory v0 = G2Point(
        [1787282038370667094324364195810339512415273589223814213215040505578200405366, 414568866548933554513940840943382696902163788831396286279770126458218272940],
        [6560020551439455112781785895092032589010633560844445112872109862153018855017, 19411093226570397520343120724285433000937737461010544490862811136406407315543]
    );

    G2Point memory v1 = G2Point(
        [14831125462625540363404323739936082597729714855858291605999144010730542058037, 8342129546329626371616639780890580451066604883761980695690870205390518348707],
        [808186590373043742842665711030588185456231663895663328011864547134240543671, 1856705676948889458735296604372981546875220644939188415241687241562401814459]
    );

    G2Point memory v2 = G2Point(
        [12507030828714819990408995725310388936101611986473926829733453468215798265704, 16402225253711577242710704509153100189802817297679524801952098990526969620006],
        [18717845356690477533392378472300056893077745517009561191866660997312973511514, 20124563173642533900823905467925868861151292863229012000403558815142682516349]
    );

    G1Point memory h0 = hashToG1(message0);
    G1Point memory h1 = hashToG1(message1);
    G1Point memory h2 = hashToG1(message2);

    G1Point[] memory a = new G1Point[](numberOfSigners + 1);
    G2Point[] memory b = new G2Point[](numberOfSigners + 1);
    a[0] = negate(signature);
    a[1] = h0;
    a[2] = h1;
    a[3] = h2;
    b[0] = P2();
    b[1] = v0;
    b[2] = v1;
    b[3] = v2;

    return pairing(a, b);
}

/// @return the result of computing the pairing check
/// e(p1[0], p2[0]) *  .... * e(p1[n], p2[n]) == 1
/// For example pairing([P1(), P1().negate()], [P2(), P2()]) should
/// return true.
function pairing(G1Point[] memory p1, G2Point[] memory p2) internal returns (bool) {
    require(p1.length == p2.length);
    uint elements = p1.length;
    uint inputSize = elements * 6;
    uint[] memory input = new uint[](inputSize);

    for (uint i = 0; i < elements; i++)
    {
        input[i * 6 + 0] = p1[i].X;
        input[i * 6 + 1] = p1[i].Y;
        input[i * 6 + 2] = p2[i].X[0];
        input[i * 6 + 3] = p2[i].X[1];
        input[i * 6 + 4] = p2[i].Y[0];
        input[i * 6 + 5] = p2[i].Y[1];
    }

    uint[1] memory out;
    bool success;

    assembly {
        success := call(sub(gas, 2000), 8, 0, add(input, 0x20), mul(inputSize, 0x20), out, 0x20)
    // Use "invalid" to make gas estimation work
        switch success case 0 {invalid()}
    }
    require(success);
    return out[0] != 0;
}

/// Convenience method for a pairing check for two pairs.
function pairing2(G1Point memory a1, G2Point memory a2, G1Point memory b1, G2Point memory b2) internal returns (bool) {
    G1Point[] memory p1 = new G1Point[](2);
    G2Point[] memory p2 = new G2Point[](2);
    p1[0] = a1;
    p1[1] = b1;
    p2[0] = a2;
    p2[1] = b2;
    return pairing(p1, p2);
}

function hashToG1(bytes memory message) internal returns (G1Point memory) {
    uint256 h = uint256(keccak256(message));
    return mul(P1(), h);
}

function modPow(uint256 base, uint256 exponent, uint256 modulus) internal returns (uint256) {
    uint256[6] memory input = [32, 32, 32, base, exponent, modulus];
    uint256[1] memory result;
    assembly {
        if iszero(call(not(0), 0x05, 0, input, 0xc0, result, 0x20)) {
            revert(0, 0)
        }
    }
    return result[0];
}

/// @return the negation of p, i.e. p.add(p.negate()) should be zero.
function negate(G1Point memory p) internal returns (G1Point memory) {
    // The prime q in the base field F_q for G1
    uint q = 21888242871839275222246405745257275088696311157297823662689037894645226208583;
    if (p.X == 0 && p.Y == 0)
        return G1Point(0, 0);
    return G1Point(p.X, q - (p.Y % q));
}

/// @return the sum of two points of G1
function add(G1Point memory p1, G1Point memory p2) internal returns (G1Point memory r) {
    uint[4] memory input;
    input[0] = p1.X;
    input[1] = p1.Y;
    input[2] = p2.X;
    input[3] = p2.Y;
    bool success;
    assembly {
        success := call(sub(gas, 2000), 6, 0, input, 0xc0, r, 0x60)
    // Use "invalid" to make gas estimation work
        switch success case 0 {invalid()}
    }
    require(success);
}
/// @return the product of a point on G1 and a scalar, i.e.
/// p == p.mul(1) and p.add(p) == p.mul(2) for all points p.
function mul(G1Point memory p, uint s) internal returns (G1Point memory r) {
    uint[3] memory input;
    input[0] = p.X;
    input[1] = p.Y;
    input[2] = s;
    bool success;
    assembly {
        success := call(sub(gas, 2000), 7, 0, input, 0x80, r, 0x60)
    // Use "invalid" to make gas estimation work
        switch success case 0 {invalid()}
    }
    require(success);
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed it but I still does not work. I used `0.5.9` but 
I got the following error. 
`browser/Pairing.sol:1:1: ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.5.9+commit.e560f70d.Emscripten.clang - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
pragma solidity ^0.4.14;
^----------------------^`

Comment: Answer update with the code for compiler version `0.5.9`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you tell me how u can modify contracts so it can work fine with other compliers

Comment: In this case it was easy because you only need to change the `pragma` and correct the compilation errors/warnings. But I recommend to revise all the code.