# web3.eth.sign not returning a valid signature - Or how else does this work?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, signature, ethereumjs, ecrecover

EDIT: **Problem Solved; working example of login below**

I use the sha3 of a message I want to sign with eth.sign
`m = web3.sha3("Please work.")`

I then run`eth.sign(eth.coinbase, m)`

And it returns me: `0x1c28d6720234343026c24718728cf0c251b0d09c87c32a6e380396a3360065290d0e7ec99a48e547e36645cecc11fd8d09742955c3d16c32eb75d9b24dd158d754`

Theoretically, I would be able to derive the validity of the signature from this.

`r = 0x1c28d6720234343026c24718728cf0c251b0d09c87c32a6e380396a336006529`

`s = 0x0d0e7ec99a48e547e36645cecc11fd8d09742955c3d16c32eb75d9b24dd158d7`

`v = 54`?! ( I was under the impression this would  be a 0 or 1. For ecrecover I tried 27 and 28 )

Now I plug these into ecrecover(m, v, r, s) and I get...

With 27: `0x8c6c953abf2957f7fec4c689f8fe2ff09b81b245`

With 28: `0xb8feaa9b9bfd7f10caefdc6d7baa1f74c37cedef`

What in the world is going on? I'm trying to implement a login for my application using web3 and this is a major roadblock. I'm hoping you geniuses can correct me where I'm wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Related, http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2256

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I came across the answer myself, See working code below**. I was following [this guide](https://hackernoon.com/never-use-passwords-again-with-ethereum-and-metamask-b61c7e409f0d) which I would not recommend!.

I was also using parity in geth mode to sign the data, which I also would not recommend. Switching to plain old geth RPC gave me more sane results.

That being said, **beware of v!**. There is a bug between implementations of geth which will return **either 00/01 or 1b/1c** for v. I solved my problem by using ethereumjs-util's **fromRpcSig** method, which accounts for the bug. If the following doesn't work try importing web3 and using its sha3 method with ethUtils toBuffer.

Here's a complete snippet of code client side and server side which implement login:

**CLIENT**

```
function login() {
  let data = web3.sha3('hello world');
  web3.eth.sign(web3.eth.defaultAccount, data, (err, result) => {
    if (!err) {
      axios.post(url + '/login', {
        addr: web3.eth.defaultAccount,
        sig: result
      }).then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });

    }
  });
}
```

**SERVER**

```
var ethUtils = require('ethereumjs-util');

let addr = req.body.addr;
let sig = req.body.sig;

let signature = ethUtils.fromRpcSig(sig);

let data = 'hello world';

let pubKey = ethUtils.ecrecover(
  ethUtils.sha3(data),
  signature.v,
  signature.r,
  signature.s);

let foundAddr = '0x' + ethUtils.pubToAddress(pubKey).toString('hex');

if (foundAddr === addr) {
  // Hooray! The user's signature proves they are who they say they are!
} else {
  // Not authenticated successfully
}
```