# How can I verify a signature with the web3 javascript API?

Tags: web3js, signature, cryptography

Using the javascript web3 API I can [create a signature](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsign) like this:

```
> web3.eth.sign(eth.coinbase, "0xdeadbeef")
"0xd3fe64b6f0920593cc4afb1321d592ae91e25fe1a0216e9002a4a6580fb2698c5ec62491c62557b8cc8f64533a5097b3ffb68208952b30cb27ed0a56ae21682201"
```

Now I'd like to verify that the signature is correct; doing so in a contract is already documented [elsewhere](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/710/how-can-i-verify-a-cryptographic-signature-that-was-produced-by-an-ethereum-addr), but I am looking for a way to do this using `web3`. (How) can this be done?

Comment: does this help ? http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1794/54

Comment: @euri10 thanks, but I am looking for an answer that doesn't require a contract to verify

Comment: (not an answer to comment)
But I am stuck with https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15461/ethereum-signature-verification-not-matching - any suggestions on what is wrong? many thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`web3` does not support this feature yet, but [it might be coming with web3 1.0](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/404).

In the meantime you can use ethereumjs-utils [ecrecover](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-util/blob/master/docs/index.md#ecrecover) feature.
Note that this function expects `v` to be in {27, 28}, and since your signature comes from geth, (since it doesn't return signatures in the canonical format yet) you will have to add `27` to your `v`.

Given a signature `sgn` of a the hashed message `msg`, you can use the ethereumjs-util library like this:

```
r = utils.toBuffer(sgn.slice(0,66))
s = utils.toBuffer('0x' + sgn.slice(66,130))
v = utils.toBuffer('0x' + sgn.slice(130,132))
m = utils.toBuffer(msg)
pub = utils.ecrecover(m, v, r, s)
adr = '0x' + utils.pubToAddress(pub).toString('hex')
```

To do the verification in a solidity contract, check out [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/workflow-on-signing-a-string-with-private-key-followed-by-signature-verificatio/1794#1794).

Comment: While this answer may be technically correct, I didn't find it to be very useful.  In particular, starting with `0xdeadbeef` and `0xd3fe64b6f0920593cc4afb1321d592ae91e25fe1a0216e9002a4a6580fb2698c5ec62491c62557b8cc8f64533a5097b3ffb68208952b30cb27ed0a56ae21682201` it is very unclear how to use `ecrecover` in that library to actually validate the address that signed it.

Comment: Updated the answer with more detail, hopefully that will be more clear now

Comment: `v = utils.toBuffer(27) //assuming that the given value was 0` should be 27 + the last hex value of the signature (0 or 1).

Comment: Also worth noting that in `utils`, the `v` parameter should be a number, so the v line should read:
`v = utils.bufferToInt(utils.toBuffer('0x' + sgn.slice(130,132)))`

Comment: I propose to change the title adding specifying it is for web3 0.*

Comment: Is there now this functionality?

Answer (score 7):

Starting v1.0 you can use [web3.eth.accounts.recover](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#recover)

```js
// message, signature
web3.eth.accounts.recover('Some data', '0xb91467e570a6466aa9e9876cbcd013baba02900b8979d43fe208a4a4f339f5fd6007e74cd82e037b800186422fc2da167c747ef045e5d18a5f5d4300f8e1a0291c');
> "0x2c7536E3605D9C16a7a3D7b1898e529396a65c23"
```