# web3.eth.sign sometimes gives V parameter of 54 or 55, ecrecover then fails. What's going on?

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethereumjs, ecrecover

I've been using `ecrecover` and `web3.eth.sign` to authorize transactions, but when I run `web3.eth.sign` a second time on my server, the `V` part of the signature is wrong(or, at least, `ecrecover` thinks it's wrong). I read that it should be 27 or 28, but `sign()` is giving me 54 and 55. However, if I changes these to 27 and 28, respectively, `ecrecover` works again. What's going on????

```
exports.sign = async(signer, nonce, amount, forUser) => {
  // pack data into the message
  let ret = [];
  let data = (nonce * 2 ** 32) + amount;
  let hexData = web3.utils.toHex(data).slice(2);
  for(let i = hexData.length; i < 16; i++) {
    hexData = "0" + hexData
  }
  let message = "0x1337beef" + forUser.slice(2) + hexData;
  // sign the message
  let sig = (await web3.eth.sign(message, signer)).slice(2);
  let r = "0x" + sig.slice(0, 64);
  let s = "0x" + sig.slice(64, 128);
  let v = web3.utils.toDecimal('0x' + sig.slice(128, 130)) + 27;
  // THESE NEXT TWO LINES MAKE THINGS WORK BUT THEY
  // ARE STINKY AND I MUST KNOW WHY THEY ARE NEEDED!!
  if(v == 54) { v = 27;}
  if(v == 55) { v = 28;}
  ret.push(message);
  ret.push(v);
  ret.push(r);
  ret.push(s);
  return ret;
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

You have not provided many details of your setup. What backend node are you using? What signature is returned when you sign the message? Web3.js `sign` method just calls through to the nodes implementation.

As outlined in [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2866), Geth previously did not return the `v` value in the appropriate format. You had to add 27.

I suspect from brief consideration that you are using a Parity node which returns the correct `v` value. You are then adding 27 unnecessarily.

Hence why your values are too high.. by 27.

Comment: Thanks man. This is truffle(so ganache) running on my dev machine. I didnt' realize sign() was hitting the node. The thing I should have made clearer is that this function works the first time(v = 0 + 27) and then when I run it again is when it fails(v = 27 + 27). If I restart my web server(not my node) it works again.