# Is it possible to preload contracts in the genesis block?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment, testnets, contract-debugging, genesis

Here's the setup I'm trying to use:

A genesis.json with the alloc field set to include code.

```
"alloc": {
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": {
      "code": "6060604052608f8060106000396000f360606040526000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900480634e70b1dc14604157806360fe47b114606257603f565b005b604c60048050506078565b6040518082815260200191505060405180910390f35b607660048080359060200190919050506081565b005b60006000505481565b806000600050819055505b5056"
    }
}
```

Then running geth and entering (with a default account set, unlocked, and loaded):

```
var getAndSetContract = eth.contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"num","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"val","type":"uint256"}],"name":"set","outputs":[],"type":"function"}])
var getAndSet = getAndSetContract.at("0000000000000000000000000000000000000001")
getAndSet.set(2, {gas: 1000000})
miner.start()
// a few blocks quickly roll in given this is on a private testing blockchain
miner.stop()
getAndSet.num()
```

Results in a final returned value of

```
3.054357634959941643970700719428062453954541146150392020568168920432276498019e+75
```

versus the desired

```
2
```

Here's the contract source:

```
contract getAndSet {
    uint public num;
    function set(uint val){
        num = val;
    }
}
```

This whole adventure started after coming across this line in the geth source: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/290e851f57f5d27a1d5f0f7ad784c836e017c337/core/genesis.go#L56 I think I saw something about preloading contracts in the past, though I haven't been able to dig anything up. AFAIK I could be on a wild goose chase trying to make use of a half-implemented feature.

Comment: Have you tried with a higher address?  Address 1 is for ecrecover (http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/440/whats-a-precompiled-contract-and-how-are-they-different-from-native-opcodes) and you might be invoking it instead of your contract.

Comment: I tried changing it to "1000000000000000000000000000000000000002", still doesn't work though the returned value changed to _4.3592315083973277133168013697365335412971280313784556186150828777023154946048e+76_

Comment: web3.js usually needs '0x' and it might need to be added to `getAndSetContract.at("0x...`

Answer (score 5):

How did you build yor contract ?
If you want to **add a contract to genesis block** you need to build it with `solc --bin-runtime`.

By default solc and ide like remix build return code that is used for creating the contract. This code returns the actual code that is stored in the blockchain

Answer (score 2):

Your method does not return any value. Calling **set()** will return the transaction hash of the calling transaction. You also need to specify the account from which you are deploying the transaction:

```
getAndSet.set(2, {eth.accounts[0], gas: 1000000});
```

(make sure you have enough balance on that account).

Comment: I'm calling the generated constant function num() which returns the variable by the same name: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#accessor-functions

Comment: Oh, I see. Have you tried specifying the account from which the contract deployment transaction is made?

Comment: I have the default account set, the _from_ field in the transaction object defaults to it

Comment: Not always. I have run into this a few days ago. It's much safer to explicitly specify all fields.

Comment: Blocks are showing transactions occurring and the nonce of the default account is incrementing. Interacting with the contract also works fine when deploying another instance manually using the same bytecode.

Comment: @JeffreyB.Petersen did you find a solution ??

Comment: @JeffreyB.Petersen any solution you found?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this old question about preloading a contract into the genesis file, so the answer is yes and for people who don't want to use solc (--bin-runtime) you can:

- Deploy your contract into your network
- get back the bytecode deployed by using (after attaching to geth)

  web3.eth.getCode("0xEc76BC7094f17fE3C987d3eb574C765219B7F1bF")
  "0x608060405260043610610112576000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463fffffff.."

NB: the bytecode returned byremix doesn't work

- copy the result into your genesis file with an address of your choice as following

  "8c7aD47113641cA92b138470620A5A39b2f7B9e8": {
  "code":"0x608060405260043610610112576000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ffffffff...."
- restart the network