# How was an address like 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001 generated?

Tags: blockchain, ether, addresses, private-key

How were the private keys for addresses like 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001 generated in ethereum? Surely they weren't made at random? Please let me know. How is it valid?

Comment: Jesbus where did you create this address at?

Answer (score 1):

There is no known private key for that address.

You don't need a private key to generate an address. You don't even need any fancy software. Just write `0x` and add 40 hexadecimal digits of your choice:

`0x012345678901234567890123456789ABCDEFABCD`

There we go, we've just created an address without a private key. Don't send anything to such addresses, because those funds will be irretrievably lost.

https://etherscan.io/address/0x012345678901234567890123456789ABCDEFABCD

Comment: Also addresses 1, 2, 3, 4 belong to precompiled contracts https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/440/whats-a-precompiled-contract-and-how-are-they-different-from-native-opcodes