# What is "Opcodes view" at etherscan?

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, contract-invocation, etherscan

Studying the [etherscan](http://etherscan.io/) platform and some contracts,

`-->> accounts >> contract accounts >> selecting one contract`,

under *Contract Code* there is an option to switch between **Bytecodes View** and **Opcodes View**.

What exactly is **Opcodes View** here and what does it represent?

There are some keywords like `PUSH1`, `MSTORE`, `MLOAD`, `DUP1`, `GAS`, `SUB` and `CALLCODE` in this view that repeat frequently.

What are these and what do they do?

Comment: Probable duplicate of the question to which this is an answer: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/120/52

Comment: For a more general computer science answer, opcodes are explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opcode (In which case possible flag of off-topic as it's not Ethereum-specific... )

Answer (score 3):

Opcodes are the individual instructions that the Ethereum Virtual Machine (EVM) understands. You're looking at the equivalent of X86 assembly language, but for the EVM instead of your computer.

Comment: but these are for contract creation isn't it? is there a way to figure out what are the opcodes for a function call?