# Is there any reference on writing contracts directly with the bytecode language?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, dapp-development, bytecode

It would be great to have a complete reference of all the opcodes available, their exact effects and costs, and an example "Hello World" in ethereum assembly.

Edit: this question isn't a duplicate of for the reasons explained on my first comment below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What OPCODES are available for the Ethereum EVM?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/119/what-opcodes-are-available-for-the-ethereum-evm)

Comment: @NicolasMassart No! That is the thread I've been looking at before asking this. It doesn't have all the information I need, otherwise I'd not have made this question. Notice that the answer doesn't inform: 1. costs; 2. exact effects (it only provides a human-friendly summary, but exact means in/out types, etc.); 3. a "assembly" hello world - all of which I'm asking for here. In fact, I couldn't find a single up-to-date cost table on the internet (since I believe the yellow paper is outdated after the last hard forks).

Comment: ok, m'y bad. Keep asking.

Comment: you are right the information about opcopdes are scattered between the yellow paper and official doc, it will be a good idea to have such reference with updated costs and expected new opcodes and more..