# Can a contract fetch the global block gas limit?

Tags: solidity, evm, remix, opcode, assembly

The [OPCODE](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/119/what-opcodes-are-available-for-the-ethereum-evm) `GASLIMIT` gets the block's gas limit. Could in-line assembly,

```
    uint gasLimit;

    assembly {
        gasLimit := gaslimit
    }
```

fetch the gas limit ?

```
contract B {

function getGasLimit() returns (uint) {
    uint gasLimit;

    assembly {
        gasLimit := gaslimit
    }
    return gasLimit;

}

}
```

Using https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/, with a gaslimit set to 3000000, `getGasLimit()` returns 6000000.

Why does it return twice the gas limit ?

[image]

Comment: After a little testing, I think this may actually be a bug with browser solidity setting the gas limit to twice the requested amount. Try it in, testrpc or on the real chain, it works for me

Comment: That was my guess too. Tested it on Ropsten test net, seems to work there, http://imgur.com/a/pkcoC

Comment: Not a bug, actually, just bad design. Looking at the code, it seems that the "gas limit" is actually the gas limit for each *transaction*, not the block gas limit. The browser VM automatically sets the block gas limit to twice the transaction gas. You can see this if you just look at the `msg.gas` for the transactions being sent. It will be what you put in the `gas limit` field (minus a bit)

Comment: I submitted an issue/PR https://github.com/ethereum/browser-solidity/issues/370

Comment: Please post your answer @TjadenHess.

Answer (score 2):

This confusion was due to  ambiguity in the term "gas limit," which in browser solidity meant *per transaction* gas, but OP assumed meant the *block* gas limit. The confusion was compounded by the fact that the block gas limit in the browser VM defaults to twice the transaction gas limit.

I submitted a PR, which was merged, and now the label says "Transaction gas limit" which should hopefully be clearer