# Is there a table of EVM instructions and their gas costs?

Tags: gas, evm, opcode, yellow-paper

The EVM instructions are in the yellow paper, or they are summed up in [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/119/what-opcodes-are-available-for-the-ethereum-evm). But their gas costs are not there. Where can I find a list of all instructions with their associated gas costs?

Comment: Is there an updated table that reflects changes in gas price post EIP158?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12405)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What OPCODES are available for the Ethereum EVM?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/119/what-opcodes-are-available-for-the-ethereum-evm)

Comment: Probably not a duplicate, as this question is specifically asking about gas costs, which the other question doesn't mention.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The [Yellow Paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) is actively maintained and should always be current, and it's not as easy as a table, but the gas costs are there in **Appendix G. Fee Schedule and read it with Appendix H**.

---

Historically:

A spreadsheet of opcodes and their gas costs that Ethereum launched with are [**here**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m89CVujrQe5LAFJ8-YAUCcNK950dUzMQPMJBxRtGCqs/edit#gid=0).

It has some analysis per [How were gas costs chosen for the Ethereum Virtual Machine instructions?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52/how-were-gas-costs-chosen-for-the-ethereum-virtual-machine-instructions)

The spreadsheet is titled 1.0 gas costs, so it might not be updated.

**edit 2017-12-11:** here is the [EIP-150 revision of the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n6mRqkBz3iWcOlRem_mO09GtSKEKrAsfO7Frgx18pNU/edit#gid=0)

Here is a small snippet from it:

```
ADD .... 3
MUL .... 5
SUB .... 3
DIV .... 5
SDIV ... 5
MOD .... 5
SMOD ... 5
ADDMOD . 8
MULMOD . 8
```

Comment: This data is (has to be) also available in the source code format in node applications.

Comment: Thanks, I missed appendix G of the yellowpaper, I thought only appendix H was relevant

Comment: An updated version of the spreadsheet is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n6mRqkBz3iWcOlRem_mO09GtSKEKrAsfO7Frgx18pNU/edit#gid=0

Comment: @maurelian Sorry to resurrect this. How are the values for those tagged Formulae calculated?

Comment: @Meshugah, The only resources I'm aware of are at the right hand side of that table, or Appendix H of the yellow paper. https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf

Answer (score 8):

If you're looking for such a table for the purpose of golfing down contract gas cost, I'd recommend you bookmark `protocol_params.go`.

It is good for two reasons:

1. It is the source of truth. The gas costs specified in that file are what a full node really meters.
2. It lists the important numbers you really need. For example, the usual gas table doesn't show how storage cost works and they don't tell you much about pre-compiled contracts.

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/params/protocol_params.go

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of reference websites for EVM opcodes:

- crytic's [evm-opcodes](https://github.com/crytic/evm-opcodes) repo
- [ethereum.org](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/evm/opcodes/)
- [ethervm.io](https://ethervm.io/)
- [evm.codes](https://www.evm.codes/)

My favorite one is [evm.codes](https://www.evm.codes/):

[image: evm.codes screenshot]