# what are the technological limits of a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, blockchain

I know that:

- a smart contract cannot initiate any type of transaction but needs an external trigger. Each transaction is triggered by an EOA
- Smart contracts cannot subscribe to events or access them directly

but are there other limits?

Comment: why do you need these limits? is this a homework?

Comment: Size limit, cannot be upgraded

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Technological limits" is a quite broad term, but some other relevant limits are, for example:

- Maximum contract size of 24 kB (see in [this article](https://cointelegraph.com/news/new-standard-to-avoid-ethreum-contract-size-limitation-developed))
- Limited stack depth of 1024 (see deprecated [Call Depth Attack](https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices/known_attacks/#call-depth-attack-deprecated))
- And most importantly, every computation requires gas, which is limited by your gas limit (see [gas costs for EVM instructions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/is-there-a-table-of-evm-instructions-and-their-gas-costs))

For a more detailed analysis of the performance of Smart Contracts, I can recommend you [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/335399898_Performance_and_Scalability_of_Private_Ethereum_Blockchains) by Di Angelo and Salzer.