# Gas in ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, gas

Will it be right to say ?

```
Gas is a very small quantity of ether.
```

**TRUE OR FALSE?**

I read somewhere:

Gas refers to the fee, or pricing value, required to successfully conduct a transaction or execute a contract on the Ethereum blockchain platform. Priced in small fractions of the cryptocurrency ether (ETH), commonly referred to as gwei and sometimes also called nanoeth, the gas is used to allocate resources of the Ethereum virtual machine (EVM) so that decentralized applications such as smart contracts can self-execute in a secured but decentralized fashion.

bit confused. I thought gas is the computational power.

Comment: I believe that it'ss quite inaccurate. Although an easy explanation to a newbie to the blockchain. But the line `commonly referred to as gwei` for gas is unacceptable. Gas is unitless and gas * gas price forme the fees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Gas is a very small quantity of ether.

False.

Gas is an abstract unit of work. Each EVM opcode has an associated gas cost, which reflects the amount of computation required to run it. (See:[Is there a table of EVM instructions and their gas costs?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/is-there-a-table-of-evm-instructions-and-their-gas-costs))

You have a to pay a small amount of ETH - in Gwei (10<sup>-9</sup> ETH) - per unit of gas. (The amount that you spend per gas is the *gas price*.)

So this part:

> Priced in small fractions of the cryptocurrency ether (ETH), commonly referred to as gwei and sometimes also called nanoeth, the gas is used to allocate resources of the Ethereum virtual machine (EVM)

...*does* make sense, though the wording is a bit ambiguous, and could be worded in a clearer way (IMO). It's saying that each unit of gas (i.e. each small piece of work) will need to be paid for in ETH.