# How to get smart contract run time bytecode from network without compiling anything?

Tags: windows, bytecode

Simple question, but I couldn’t find the answer anywhere. How to get the exact bytecode of a smart contract (not creation bytecode) when the source code of contract is available on https://etherscan.io ?

This is for already deployed contracts.

Comment: Even without any constructor, the creation bytecode contains more function than the resulting contract.

Comment: Why don't you want the creation bytecode? It is the code of the contract, so...?

Comment: @Andromelus : creation bytecode contains the code of the contract, but it’s not the contract… https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/23092/25002

Comment: The creation bycode is the contract. You are taking the comment made in the answer too far implying that these are two different things. The deployed contract seems to be missing only the opcodes of the constructor, so having the creation bycode you have everything you need.

Comment: @Jaime : which require assembly knowledge to get where the actual contract starts from.