# solidity binary code with multiple "stop"

Tags: solidity

I find some sol contains multiple "stop" instr. For example, [this address](https://etherscan.io/address/1b060a62ebba2c6286f60b137d2d30fd777682d5#code) has binary "0000000000000000", which means they have a lot of "stop". Anybody know what is the source code can cause this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zeroes you see in the bytecode are produced by:

```
PUSH13 0x01000000000000000000000000
PUSH1 0x04
...
PUSH21 0x010000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

`PUSH1 (0x60)` means place 1 byte item on stack 
`PUSH13 (0x6c)` means place 13 bytes item on stack 
*..and so on..*

There is also only one `STOP` in this bytecode which is represented as `0x00`.

---

[Switch to Opcodes view](https://etherscan.io/address/1b060a62ebba2c6286f60b137d2d30fd777682d5#code) 
[What OPCODES are available for the Ethereum EVM](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/120/9938)